# If determinants $D$ and $D_1$ are given, how do we find the determinant $D_2$ such that $D_2=\frac{D}{D_1}$?

Tags: contest-math, determinant

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> If the determinant $D=\begin{vmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & 1\\
> \alpha+\beta & \alpha^2+\beta^2 & 2\alpha\beta\\
> \alpha+\beta & 2\alpha\beta & \alpha^2+\beta^2
> \end{vmatrix}$ and $D_1=\begin{vmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & \alpha & \beta\\
> 0 & \beta & \alpha
> \end{vmatrix}$, then find the determinant $D_2$ such that $D_2=\frac{D}{D_1}$.

I calculated $D=(\alpha^2-\beta^2)(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha+\beta-2)$

And $D_1=\alpha^2-\beta^2$

Thus, I thought the answer would be $(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha+\beta-2)$

But the answer given is $\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & \alpha & \beta\\
1 & \beta & \alpha
\end{vmatrix}$

If I calculate its value, it indeed matches with that of mine. But **how do we find the answer in the required format**?

Before this question, a note was written: "If $D_1$ is the determinant formed by replacing the elements of determinant $D$ of order $n$ by their corresponding cofactors then $D_1=D^{n-1}$"

Not sure if this note is meant for this question, but I tried writing cofactors for each element but still couldn't solve this question. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Many matrices have the same determinant, e.g. you could take a diagonal matrix like $diag(1,\,(\alpha-\beta),\,(\alpha+\beta-2))$.

Comment: @Berci I agree. So, going backward won't make sense. We need to find the determinant in the required format directly but don't know how.

Comment: The exercise doesn't specify that a certain format is required. Did you copy the exercise statement verbatim?

Comment: @Christoph I have copied the statement verbatim.

Comment: Then the exercise statement is poorly written. Also note that when $\alpha=\beta$, the fraction $\frac D {D_1}$ isn't even defined.

Comment: @Christoph yes, that's a very valid observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a somewhat weird formulation of the problem, in my opinion, but what they meant was presumably that the matrices $A$ and $A_1$ are given, and you want to find some matrix $A_2$ such that $D_2 = \det(A_2)$ equals $D/D_1=\det(A)/\det(A_1)$. And the matrix that they have chosen is $A_2 = A_1^{-1} A$. (You can check quite easily that $A_1 A_2 = A$.) But it's not the only possible answer, since there are many matrices with the same determinant.